# Hibernate Search issue on Amazon

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

***Technology Versions*:**

```
Hibernate 3.6.5

Hibernate Search 3.4.0

Lucene (lucene-core-*.jar) 3.1.0

Spring 3.1.0.M2
```

***Hibernate (Search) Configuration*:**

```
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/some/dir</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy">native</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use">false</prop>
```

***The issue*:**

Our application is deployed in Amazon (AWS cloud), but we've faced this issue in our local clusters as well:

The application design is such that there is a `Thread` that is spawned from within the main (Web) application wherefrom we need to update an *Indexed* entity. Basically it's like a status monitor thread which reads a .status file and updates the database every 30 seconds or so. This keeps happening for about 10mins to 1/2 an hour on an average.
The issue we see is that: every few days we need to regenerate the indexes because Hibernate Search stops returning anything for the entity in question (the one discussed above).

I went through few forums and seems it is suggested that only a single thread should be updating the Lucene indexes. But it is also given that index writing is thread-safe. So even if multiple threads are writing to the same index, I still expect that it should not cause the issue (of nothing being returned in the search). That is to say, I may get stale status of the entity in question, but still, *something* should be returned.

We're using the default IndexReader/Writer implementation of Hibernate Search.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should point out in the question what you where using NFS, which the Hibernate Search reference manual explicitly discourages because of locking problems. Use the Infinispan Directory if you need real time updates, or setup the JMS master/slave approach as documented. You could write a backend making use of Amazon queue service too.

Answer (score 2):

here are some thoughts.

> I went through few forums and seems it is suggested that only a single
>   thread should be updating the Lucene indexes.

That's not generally true. Lucene and Hibernate Search allow multiple index writer, **BUT** access to the index must be properly synchronized which happens via Lucene's *org.apache.lucene.store.LockFactory*. The lock factory is configurable and you are using the native one via the property *hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy*. The problem might be that this strategy is file based. I don't know much about Amazon's distributed file system internal workings, but I would imagine that file locks just don't work in this case. You might need to implement a custom lock strategy.

> But it is also given that index writing is thread-safe. So even if multiple threads are 
>   writing to the same index, I still expect that it should not cause the issue

Correct, provided the locking works.

An alternative is to work w/o locks (setting *hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy* to *none*) provided you can guarantee that only your update thread will ever write to the index. Do you have aside of the update thread automatic indexing enabled? If so try turning it of (permitted your use case allows you to).

Comment: You're right, this seems to be a file locking issue on Amazon. To verify, I carried-out Lucene's LockStressTest (w/ LockVerfifyServer) on it -- and observed that at high load, lock acquisition fails on multiple occasions. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a resolution for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who have landed here looking for a solution -- here's what we did finally, which seems to have addressed the issue (we've load-tested this fix on AWS and have had no issues so far):

We wrote our implementation of a lock factory based on Lucene's `NativeFSLockFactory`. We modified the `obtain` method so as to retry obtaining the lock a couple of times before giving-up. We added a short lag (`sleep`) between retries to handle `NFS` latencies.

We tested this fix with Lucene's `LockVerifyServer` and observed that under high load, even though a few of the lock obtain requests have to wait to obtain the lock -- but eventually every lock obtain request is addressed. In real-time, this interprets to a successful update of the index files.

Thank you [Hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115835/hardy) for showing us the path. :)

**Update:** Yesterday, we had to bump-up the retry count to a higher number ~30 because we faced an index update slippage with the previous value of 3. Things seem fine thereafter.

Comment: If you only had mentioned NFS in your question, I would have immediately told you that it's very troublesome with Lucene. That's why we created the [Infinispan Directory](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Infinispan+as+a+Directory+for+Lucene), which is now integrated in Hibernate Search as [the recommended approach](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#infinispan-directories).